# Access a field's custom class in Django's ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm working on a `ModelForm` in `Django` that uses a `Model`, which has a custom `CharField`.

When handling form errors I want to show the user valid examples (I thought this shouldn't be part of the raised `ValidationError`). However, when I try to access the fields using `myform.fields` by getting the invalid fields and the corresponding error messages using `myform.errors.items()` `type(myform.fields["myfield"])` returns `<class 'django.forms.fields.CharField'>` instead of my custom `MyField`.

Therefore `myform.fields["myfield"].test()` raises `AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'test'`.

How do I get the correct `MyField` instance from `form.fields`?

```py
class MyField(models.CharField):
    pass


class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfield = MyField(max_length=20)


class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        exclude = tuple()
        model = MyModel


myform = MyForm()
print(type(myform.fields["myfield"]))
```

Comment: Note that *model fields* are something different than *form fields*. The default form field for a `CharField`, and since you did not override this, this will raise an error.

Comment: How do I override the form field for a `CharField`?

Answer (score 0):

A *model field* is different than a *form field*. A model field focusses on *storing* the data in the database, a *form field*.

You can define an extra form field, for example:

```
# app_name/forms/fields.py

from django.forms import CharField

class MyField(Field):
    # …
    pass
```

Now we can specify this form field as the default field for the `MyField` *model field*:

```
app_name/fields.py

class MyField(models.CharField):
    
    # …
    
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        return super().formfield(**{
            'form_class': app_name.forms.fields.MyField,
            **kwargs,
        })
```

If you thus now use your `MyField` *model* field (the second code fragment), it will use the `MyField` *form* field (the first code fragment).

Comment: Thank you - I'll have a look at it tomorrow!

Comment: How can I access now the attributes of the `MyField(models.CharField)` in the `MyField(forms.CharField)`?

Comment: @5t4cktr4c3: you don't. Form fields have *nothing* to do with *model fields*. Model fields store data, form fields are used to render/validate/clean data of a form.

Comment: So what alternative do I have when I validate the value in an `MyField(models.CharField)` -instance using its attributes and want to show the usage with examples based on the instance's attributes from the the form?

Comment: @5t4cktr4c3: if you make use of a `ModelForm`, it is better to specify the validators in the model field, with the `validators=...` parameter, you can pass functions that will be checked: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/validators/#writing-validators

Comment: Yes, the validator is in the the model field. My point/question is how do I get specific attributes of the model instance from the modelform to print a custom usage text.

Comment: @5t4cktr4c3: do you *manually* render the form, since by default if you use `{{ form.as_p }}` it will show the error messages.

Comment: I need to mention that I use ajax to send and validate the form. Eventually I came up with adding the model (`self`) in the `formfield`-method to the keyworded-args. In the FormField I grab that module and set it as attribute: `self.model = model`